# UITableView cells updates just after restart of app

Tags: ios, swift

There's a button in another ViewController, if I press on it, I should see the time when I pressed on the button.

The button works, but the table won't refresh after I click on a refresh button, place the refresh on the ViewDidAppear function doesn't work as well.

I need to quit the app, close it from multitasking and open it again, then the time that I pressed on the button shows. What should I do to make the refresh button work?

(Both View Controllers are in the same storyboard, the second one extends the first one)

First View Controller:

```
class Tracking: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UITableView!
var activities = [String]()
var userData = false

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activities.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.row]
    return(cell)
}

@IBAction func Reload(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    activity.reloadData()
}
.
.
.
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class Activity: Tracking {
    .
    .
    .
@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isPlayed += 1
    userData = true
    UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "userData")
    let playElm = playStr + " בשעה: " + getTime()
    activities.append(playElm)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(activities, forKey: "activities")
}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: "There's a button in another ViewController" From your code the button seems to be on the same ViewController of the Button. How do you manage that exactly?

Comment: @Larme I've updated the question.

Comment: @matanm How you're fetching activities from `Userdefaults` in First View Controller?

Comment: @ImadAli Like that: http://imgur.com/a/hxh9Q

Comment: @matanm If you debug, Are you seeing saved activities in `viewDidLoad` First VC?

Comment: @ImadAli I didn't understand what you said..

Comment: @matanm Is your array activities is having data before you reload.

Comment: @ImadAli If I pressed the button. If I didn't press it, I have the "no user data"

Comment: So you mean to say that the `Userdefaults` is not holding the array value when you quit the app from background.

Comment: @ImadAli It is, but when I try to reload it when I'm inside the app it doesn't work. I need to quit the app, kill its process and than launch it again. The problem is that I don't know how to refresh the table with the new content inside the array.

Comment: your activities data is not changing, thats' why it's not refreshing table. You need to fetch data for activities from userDefaults before reloadData() method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch from user defaults your new date in activities array and after that you can reloadData

```
@IBAction func Reload(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.activities = UserDefaults.standard.get( forKey: "activities")
    activity.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `activity.reloadData()`, you're telling the table view to update its rows and what they display based solely on the contents of your `activities` property that you defined with the line:

```
var activities = [String]()
```

When you're loading the app from a fresh start, that `activities` array of strings hasn't been filled with anything. I see you save data to UserDefaults, but I don't see anywhere from which you read it.

Put this next code in your `viewDidLoad()`. `viewDidAppear()` isn't what you want to use for this purpose.

```
activities = UserDefaults.standard.get(forKey: "activities")
activity.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working automaticlly without the refresh button. The code that Svetoslav Bramchev wrote works when I place it in viewDidAppear. Thanks for your help!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userData = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userData")
    if(userData == true){
        activities = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "activities") as! [String]
    } else {
        activities.append("no data")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(activities, forKey: "activities")
        if(activities[0] == "no data"){
            activities.remove(at: 0)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(activities, forKey: "activities")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    activities = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "activities") as! [String]
    activity.reloadData()
}
```